# Accessing Google Drive files with command line in Linux

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to be able to upload/download files from my Google Drive using a command line in Linux. I found an application called *gdrive* but Google refuses to authenticate this program. Any suggestions?

Comment: you will need to clone the gdrive project, then create your own project on the Google API console, and put the new project credentials into the gdrive source. See this issue https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/issues/553

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question and the answer lies within the issues of the github project